# Is a python interface similar to metaclasses?

Tags: java, python, python-3.x

Python doesn't seem to need interfaces like java since it has extensive use of inheritance and overloading, but would a metaclass be similar to an interface?

Comment: Is an apple similar to an orange?

Comment: I think you're looking for [abc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html)

Comment: Metaclasses bear almost no conceptual resemblance to interfaces whatsoever.

Comment: Python has a concept of "mixins". These can be used in some of the same situations where interfaces are used, although they are not the same...